# WMV streaming file size limit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, video-streaming, wmv

I have a windows media player embedded in my web page view:

```
 <div id="divCourseVideo" style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;" class="container">
        <OBJECT style="display:inline-block" ID="CoursePlayer" HEIGHT="400" WIDTH="400" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="video/x-ms-wmv">
            <param name='URL' value="@Url.Action("ShowMovie", "OLT", new { courseId = Model.ID })" />
            <param name='autoStart' value="true" />
            <param name='currentPosition' value="false" />
            <param name='showControls' value="true" />
        </OBJECT>


    </div>
```

The ShowMovie action extracts a video stream from the database and sends it to the view with this:

```
 public void ShowMovie(string courseId)
    {
        CourseVideo video = Repository.GetCourseVideoStream(courseId);
        var bytesinfile = new byte[video.VideoStream.Length];
        video.VideoStream.Read(bytesinfile, 0, (int)video.VideoStream.Length);
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(bytesinfile);
    }
```

When I use a video with a size of about 10K or so will play fine.  But if I use a file that is about 137K or so the file never plays.  Is it too large?

When I use F12 to see the network activity I see the file is trying to come down as text/html.  Why is that?  I also see that on the GET function that it is aborting.  Why is that?  I've increased the executionTimeout value to no avail.

[image]

The information from napuza was good I was able to get the correct content type and it seems the entire file was streamed to the browser but it never plays.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the ContentType:

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "video/x-ms-wmv";
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(bytesinfile);
```

Comment: Thanks napuza.  I now see the correct content type but the large files never play.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: This is strange but I think it may have been the particular file I loaded into the database.  Once I loaded an actual file to be used in the training process, and the file is over 300MB, it played just fine - over 23 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the file in chunks:

```
response = ...    
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

response.ContentType = "video/x-ms-wmv";
response.AppendHeader("content-length", video.VideoStream.Length);

while ( response.IsClientConnected) {
    int bytesRead = video.VideoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (bytesRead == 0 ) {
        break;
    }
    response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    response.Flush();
}
response.End();
```

Comment: That helps a little.  It goes from locating media to connecting to media to opening media then jumps back to ready without playing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement [HTTP range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests).

Answer (score 0):

I've given credit to napuzba for the answer because he led me in the right direction.  I succeeded with this:

```
 CourseVideo video = Repository.GetCourseVideoStream(courseId);
        var bytesinfile = new byte[video.VideoStream.Length];
        video.VideoStream.Read(bytesinfile, 0, (int)video.VideoStream.Length);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "video/x-ms-wmv";
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", video.VideoStream.Length.ToString());
        video.VideoStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(bytesinfile);
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
```

However, some of the WMV files I've been working with still don't play.  I suspect it may have something to do with the metadata in the file.  Anyone have ideas on that?

Comment: First, check if the original file work from your local disk (URL='file://...'). If so, download the file from the site and compare its contents with the original file.